# PHP Session variable is set, but PHP doesn't see it. Very strange

Tags: php, session, session-variables

Okay, maybe this is because I've been coding for over 24 hours and my eyes are glazing over, but I'm stumped here. Why does this happen:

```
<?php
session_start();
$tmp = "index";

echo "A: " . $_SESSION['page_loaded']['index']; // returns 1
echo "B: " . $_SESSION['page_loaded'][$tmp]; // is set, but is empty
?>
```

I feel like I'm missing something very basic here but I don't know what.

Comment: Can you provide more information?

Comment: I think the problem might be somewhere else in the code, that part seems ok (to me at least)

Comment: Are you trying to put $tmp into $_SESSION["page_loaded"]? If so, I'm not sure if you can echo out the value at the same time you're placing it into your $_SESSION array. I could be mistaken, but I've never seen anybody attempt that before.

Comment: what is the value you expected to have out from tmp? is it the string "index"?

Comment: Guys, I was convinced that this was a bug in PHP. But as you guys may already be assuming, it was my fault, being stupid in two entirely different ways. My example was distilled down from something that had a typo, so what you're seeing actually works. My apologies. 26 hours and no sleep=stupid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a feeling you haven't actually cut and pasted that code? Is there anything you're leaving out?

Answer (score 1):

Where are you setting the following?

```
$_SESSION['page_loaded'][$tmp];
```

The following works:

```
<?php

    session_start();
    $tmp = "index";

    $_SESSION["page_loaded"][$tmp] = "Foo";

    echo "A: " . $_SESSION['page_loaded']["index"]; // foo
    echo "<br/>";
    echo "B: " . $_SESSION['page_loaded'][$tmp]; // foo

?>
```

Comment: Where he's setting it shouldn't matter.  The first echo line returns "1", so the second echo line should return "1" as well.

Comment: @mangst - It DOES matter. If it's not returning the expected value, then you need to look back to where you're setting it.

Comment: No it shouldn't! :P The issue is that both lines are accessing the same array element, but in different ways.  Line #1 uses an in-line string and the line #2 uses a variable containing a string.  Both strings are equal, so both should be returning the same value.

Comment: @mangst - My updated example works, which naturally causes me to want to see where/how the variable is being stored. You can mock it if you like, but I can clearly see something taking place in my example.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with the `var_dump` function to see it’s value.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
$tmp = 'index'; // Note the single quotes.
//...
echo "B: " . $_SESSION['page_loaded'][$tmp];
```

PHP interprets double and single quoted strings slightly differently. Read these articles [here](https://www.php.net/types.string) and [here](http://v1.jeroenmulder.com/weblog/2005/04/php_single_and_double_quotes.php) as that might be what you are facing.

UPDATE: Just to clarify (given the comments below) my reasoning to check if using single or double quoted strings are effecting the Original Posters problem is shown in the example below where the two strings are not equal:

```
$var = 1;

$tmpA = 'index_$var'; // will resolve to index_$var
$tmpB = "index_$var"; // will resolve to index_1

if ( $tmpA === $tmpB)
  echo 'Identical';
else
  echo 'Not Identical!'; // <--- we get this because they are NOT identical.
```

Comment: Don't think the type of quotes used would make a difference in this case.

Comment: possibly, but its about all I can see from the code posted by the OP. why down voted? its a fair enough answer.

Comment: php sees `$tmp = 'index'` as identical to `$tmp = "index"` in every way. Agree though the OP didn't post much in the way of code.

Comment: crescentfresh: yes in the example given they are identical but the real code in question potentially may have more complex values which may be constructed in a way that the type of quotes effects it.

Comment: The only difference between single and double quotes is that PHP parses variables within double quotes. That's it. Try this: if ("test" === 'test') echo 'Identical';

Comment: I'm tempted to notch this one up a level.  While PHP <em>says</em> that "index" == 'index', I have found that it will occasionally forget.

Answer (score -5):

you should use

```
 $_SESSION['page_loaded']['tmp'] = "index";
```

instead of

```
 $tmp = "index";
```

and to retrieve the value use this

```
  echo "B: " . $_SESSION['page_loaded']['tmp']; // the output is: B: index
```

(get rid of the dollar sign $)

Comment: No, this wouldn't work.  By using $_SESSION['page_loaded']['tmp'], you would be accessing a completely different array element.

Comment: @mangst: it works for me!, I have added explanation, hope it will work